# iPhone 12 Pro LiDAR API access for Safari

Tags: javascript, iphone, augmented-reality, lidar

I'm working with WebAR reality (real-time SLAM and tracking) based on WebGL.
And wondering if there any way to get access to LiDAR API and use it in the Safari browser?

I couldn't find any useful info about it.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, there is no documented direct LIDAR access on Safari.  Safari also [doesn't support](https://caniuse.com/webxr) the W3C WebXR Device API. Safari on iOS does support [AR Quick Look](https://developer.apple.com/augmented-reality/quick-look/), a feature that automatically displays any USDZ file in an AR view.